# PHP Importing CSV Files getting weird characters

Tags: php, csv

I am importing csv files and storing it in my database.

The problem is that i am getting some weird characters when trying to use `var_dump`.

Here is the image of those characters:

[image]

In the CSV, it does not look like that, it looks like this `13.05.2014 17`

So obviously there's something wrong.

So my question for this is how can I remove all of those weird characters?

Your help will be greatly appreciated!

Thank You! :)

Comment: Looks like an encoding issue

Comment: Mind your character encoding, for example use UTF-8. How is your source file encoded? How is your browser decoding the chars?

Comment: I also thought one too because I got this csv from a Norweigan client, though I am not sure if that is related.

Comment: It's probably UTF-8 encoding problem. UTF8 uses 2 bytes for one sign. Var dump result shows an extra sign for each letter. So convert Your UTF8 string to proper one. Or change Your encoding on web site to utf-8.

Answer (score 1):

You must first check your character set and then convert it. You can use
    mb_detect_encoding($out);
if you do not know the character set. However in a general case it will always be one out of them: UTF-8, ASCII, ISO-8859-1, ISO-8859-15
The result should be UTF-8 in most cases. You should adapt this PHP code to your needs.
The PHP module mb_string is necessary. Otherwise you must replace it by another conversion function.

```
$out = 'some strange character set @@@@@@@@@';
if (
    function_exists('mb_detect_encoding') &&
    is_callable('mb_detect_encoding')
) {
    $charset = mb_detect_encoding($out, 'UTF-8,ASCII,ISO-8859-1,ISO-8859-15', TRUE);
}

if (
    $charset != '' &&
    $charset != 'UTF-8'
) {
    $out =
        mb_convert_encoding(
            $out,
            'UTF-8',
            $charset
        );
}

var_dump($out);
```